# Installing karaf on fedora-Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fedora, karaf

I am trying to create an image with fedora which has karaf inside it.I am not understanding how to do this using the Dockerfile.I am using the following docker file

```
FROM fedora
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim

ENV RESOURCE_DIR /var/resources
ENV VAROPT_DIR /var/opt
ENV LOG_DIR /var/opt/log
ENV KARAF_VERSION 3.0.8
ENV OSGI_BASE /usr/local/osgi
ENV INSTANCE_NAME cus
ENV OSGI_DEPLOY_DIR /deploy


# Install Karaf
RUN mkdir -p ${OSGI_BASE}
ADD http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/karaf/3.0.8/apache-karaf-3.0.8.tar.gz ${OSGI_BASE}/
WORKDIR ${OSGI_BASE}
RUN gunzip apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION}.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION}.tar
RUN ln -s apache-karaf-${KARAF_VERSION} latest

# Cutomize to enable mount volumes
WORKDIR ${OSGI_BASE}/latest/etc
RUN sed -i 's/karaf.framework=felix/karaf.framework=equinox/' config.properties
RUN sed -i 's/^\(felix\.fileinstall\.dir\s*=\s*\).*$/\1\/deploy/' org.apache.felix.fileinstall-deploy.cfg
RUN sed -i 's%${karaf.data}%/var/opt%' org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg

# Include war as part of base feature
RUN sed -i '/^featuresBoot=/s/$/,http,war/' org.apache.karaf.features.cfg

ENV PATH ${OSGI_BASE}/latest/bin:$PATH


# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8101 8181 2181

# Define Mountable volumes
RUN mkdir -p ${LOG_DIR}
VOLUME ${VAROPT_DIR}
RUN mkdir ${OSGI_DEPLOY_DIR}
VOLUME ${OSGI_DEPLOY_DIR}

WORKDIR ${RESOURCE_DIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${RESOURCE_DIR}
```

The dockerfile runs and works fine.The only thing i dont understand is weather it has served the purpose. ie whether the karaf got copied on to the fedora os properly or did it just create a image with karaf on it.How to check it.Please help.

Comment: Did you run the image and check inside if your software works fine or not?

Comment: Yes i did ,and it was..i had understood the concept wrong.Now successfully installed fedora and karaf. :) Thanks for the help anyway